# Puppeteer page.select does not work for some elements

Tags: puppeteer, ui-automation

I'm trying to select "select option" value in https://www.gumtree.com/ But it doesn't change the select element's value
[image: Screenshot from 2020-02-20 11-43-30]

This is the html source for this component:

```
    <select name="attributes[vehicle_make]" id="vehicle_make" data-validation-group-channel="cars-vans-motorbikes-details-group" required="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="">Please select...</option>  
        <option value="abarth">Abarth</option>  
        <option value="ac">AC</option>...
    </select>
```

This is the code i'm using:

```
    const select_vehicle_type = await page.waitForSelector("#vehicle_make");
    var value = 'Audi'; // I tried both 'Audi' and 'audi' as value but both doesn't work
    await page.select('#vehicle_make', value);
```

Can someone please point out what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is I was trying to set the value to dropdown before the page setting initial value to the dropdown fetched from the server. I added timeout to wait and then used `await page.select('#vehicle_make', value);` and it worked as expected.